# limit of rows in SQL Server 2005 when performance degrades

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance

What is the limit of rows in a table for SQL Server 2005, when SQL query starts getting slower? Is there any way to find out the limit?

I understand it will depend upon the data length of a row. This will also depend on how many more data in other tables and the hardware available.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Number of indices and statistics will also impact on this.

Comment: Or how long is a floating piece of charred string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking the wrong question.

If you have the 'right' indexes to cover your query workload, the number of rows won't make much difference until you reach 10's or 100's millions of rows.

Make sure your server has enough RAM.

Answer (score 1):

There are no limits, the only restriction is hard-drive space.

The performance is based on your machine spec and how your tables are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

too many parameters that affect this number. hit and try method is the only available option

Answer (score 0):

If your performance degrades significantly as you add rows and you have good indexing, one of the most likely culprits is a poorly written query.  This is why we can't say for sure at what point it would happen, it depends greatly on exactly how you are querying your database and your database structure.

Some of the common things that can work fine in small data sets but which often work badly in larger sets:
  cursors
  correlated subqueries
  wildcards in the first character of a where condidtion
  functions 
  non-sargeable where clauses
  forgetting to index the foreign key fields